# 35 year old D.R. Dimes windsor chairs need freshening up

Tags: refinishing

I have 12 D.R. Dimes windsor chairs that were finished with some sort of painted crackle effect, dark green with peeks of red. They are approximately 35 years old and the finish is looking dull. I would appreciate advice on how to restore them.

Comment: Hard to advise without any pics to go on but a clean and wax may do enough. Waxing is in general the best way to maintain the look of all wooden furniture, in addition to regular light cleaning (dusting and the occasional wipe with a damp cloth). Both dusting and damp wiping will eventually dull finishes and waxing is the best way to get some shine back.

Comment: BTW 35 years is about the max you can expect from some finishes and some degree of restoration (up to refinishing) may then be needed. You're lucky that these have a faux worn look as that's very forgiving of further wear and finish degradation so you chose well :-)